# How to check file extension in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to check the file's capacity and extension.

```
<input type="file" id="fileup['+idx+']"> 
<input type="button" onclick="fileSizeCheck(idx)">
```

When I have this code, how do I check the extension when adding files and checking the capacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the file by adding an *onchange* event handler to the file input. Maybe save that to a variable and then use it in the *onclick* handler